# How can I divide the edge between two vertices?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

How can I split [the image shows the desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNJ4l.png)the edge between two vertices in plan that I take the edge and drag it up and down so that it echoes the shape that I leave in the image below

Comment: You did not include the image correctly, furthermore, it is impossible to interpret what it is you are asking.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering me. It's my first question in this forum and I don't know why the photo was not uploaded correctly.
I'm going to pass you the link of the photo to see if you can see it.
what I want is to be able to drag the links between two vertices to have the effect of the image without ending said connection between the vertices.

Comment: link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNJ4l.png
can you see her??